# How to define logo on my thesis template?

Tags: graphics, templates, logos

I am using [Princeton thesis template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/princeton-university-thesis) and I would like to add the LOGO of my university to the first page. 
I added following code to thesis.tex file at line 89

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{figures/Logo_UzK_colour}
\end{center}
```

and it works but with an error

```
LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

but if I use

```
\begin{document}
```

the latex could not even compile the job. 
I guess, I have to define the logo somewhere in `puthesis.cls` file, but I am very new in latex and I don't know how to write it.

Comment: You have to put the `\begin{center}` stuff *after* the `\begin{document}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: the problem is the format of writing in this template is different. everything define before \begin{document}.

Answer (score 1):

You could redefine the titlepage to include the image:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitlepage}{{
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \sc
  \vspace*{0in}

  \begin{center}% <- new
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}% <- new
  \end{center}% <- new

  \begin{center}
    \LARGE \@title
  \end{center}
  \vspace{.6in}
  \extravspace{.6in}
  \begin{center}
    \@author
  \end{center}
  \vspace{.6in}
  \extravspace{.6in}
  \begin{center}
    A Dissertation \\
    Presented to the Faculty \\
    of Princeton University \\
    in Candidacy for the Degree \\
    of Doctor of Philosophy
  \end{center}
  \vspace{.3in}
  \extravspace{.3in}
  \begin{center}
    Recommended for Acceptance \\
    by the \@deptpref \\
    \@dept \\
    Adviser: \@adviser
  \end{center}
  \vspace{.3in}
  \extravspace{.3in}
  \begin{center}
    \@submitted
  \end{center}
  \clearpage
  }}
\makeatother
```